# Thevenin equivalent of circuit with no voltage sources

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image: Circuit in question]

I need to find the Thevenin Equivalent left of the >> symbols.
Due to the lack of voltage sources I tried finding the Norton Equivalent first and came up with \$Rn=R_O\$, \$v_{th}=i_S \cdot R_O\$. Is that correct? If not how does one handle this case?

Comment: It is trivial to go from Norton to Thevenin and vice versa.

Comment: Also, I guarantee you that \$R_N = R_O\$ is incorrect. You haven't accounted for the VCCS, which is configured to act just like another resistor in parallel with \$R_O\$.

Comment: -oldfart; I know but doing that in this case yields a result which is independent of g, so i suppose i am missing something

Comment: what you've tried is correct but it's just an intermediate result: a Thevenin source connected to a dependent current source. Now use it to determine short circuit current and open circuit voltage

Comment: Can you find the open-circuit output voltage and short-circuit output current of the circuit?

Comment: wait, is correct to say that v sub x is equal to Vth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

- To find Rth, open circuit all independent current sources, short all independent voltage sources.
- Connect a fictitious 1V source at the open ckt terminal.
- Find the current driven by 1V source.
- If I is the current driven by 1V source, then \$\frac{V}{I} = \frac{1}{I}\$ is the load seen by the voltage source. i.e., Rth.
  $$I = I_{Ro} + gv_x$$
  vx = voltage across Ro = 1V
  $$\implies I = \frac{1}{Ro}+g = \frac{(1+gRo)}{Ro}$$
  $$\therefore R_{th} = 1/I = \frac{Ro}{(1+gRo)} $$
- To find Vth, go back to the original ckt.
  [image]

Vth is the voltage drop across Ro which is same as vx.

- Write ohms law equation for voltage across Ro
  $$(i_s-gv_x)Ro= v_x$$
  $$\implies v_x = i_s\frac{Ro}{(1+gRo)} = V_{th}$$